# What is the significance of the old man hopping in "Lot 36"?

Tags: cabinet-of-curiosities

In the first episode of *Guillermo del Toro’s Cabinet of Curiosities*, “Lot 36”, we see the old man who rents the titular storage unit make a hopping motion before entering and after exiting the unit, which seems to have some significance.

[image: GIF of the old man hopping]

<sup>The old man takes a few steps back and then hops three times before he enters and after he exits the storage unit.</sup>

Later, we discover that the storage unit contains the body of his long-missing sister, which serves as a vessel for a demon.

However, the significance of the hopping is never explained. Why does the old man do it? Is it based on any real-life occult or mystical practices?

I thought it was a ritual to keep the demon bound, but that doesn’t seem to be the case. The demon stayed bound for days after the old man’s death, until Nick Appleton (Tim Blake Nelson) disrupted the circle around the body.

Comment: Looking at the chatter on the internet, it sounds like del Toro has intentionally included '[unexplained weird stuff](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MindScrew)' precisely to [get people talking about his show](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheWalrusWasPaul).

Comment: I assume that it was not to break the threshold somehow.